# Error Scraping Amazon Data using Beautiful Soup: Object Returns None

Tags: python, object, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The amazon id object returns None no matter what I do. As an experiment, I tried this exact code on ebay id objects, and it worked. What is different about amazon? I have also already attempted to change html.parser to lxlm and it still returns:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

The issue can be found in the getPrice() def

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import time
import smtplib

URL = 'https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/darth-vader-s-castle-75251'

headers = {'Users-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36'}

wanted = 80

email = "help@gmail.com"
password = 'password'

Server_name = 'mail.gmail.com'


MAIL_USE_SSL=True

def sendMail():
    subject = 'Ebay Price has Dropped!!'
    mailtext = "Subject:"+subject+"\n\n"+URL
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email,password)
    server.sendmail(email,email,mailtext)
    print("Sent Email")
    pass




def trackPrice():
    price = getPrice()
    if price > wanted:
        diff = (price - wanted)
        diff = round(diff,5)
        print(f"it's still ${diff} over-priced")
    else:
        print('cheaper')
        sendMail()


def getPrice():

    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text().strip()[4:]

    price = float(price)

    print(price)
    return price







if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        trackPrice()
        time.sleep(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your actual URL is something like:

```py
URL = "https://www.amazon.com/LEGO-Vaders-Castle-Building-Pieces/dp/B07J6F8H3M"
```

Then if you print the `soup` variable you will see that Amazon has detected that you are trying to scrape their page and presented you an error page instead, since the content starts with:

```html
<!--
        To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
        For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_5_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_5_ac for advertising use cases.
-->
...
```

This explains why the HTML tag with `id="priceblock_ourprice"` is not found, `find(...)` returns `None` and the `get_text()` function fails.

Comment: I appreciate that insight. I emailed the provided link, but it appears to be not accepting messages at this point in time. I will go back to scraping from other sites for now. Thanks!!